# Java Program which uses MySql running on other machine

Tags: java, mysql

I am new to programming world, and now I am writing program in Java, which connects to my internal(?!) mysql server, where is a database called testDB and table called testTable. So I am wondering, what I need to do if I want to run that program on a different machine, where is no mysql server installed/running? I bet this is not easy to make, but I really want to know how to do it - curiosity is killing me. Thank you.

Comment: When connecting to a MySQL database, whatever the language, you can choose the address of the database server. Usually you can specify the IP address. How are you connection today ?

Comment: Well, I know that, but what if I want that every program use its own database on its local computer?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to change the jdbc URL from localhost to the DBs hostname

e.g.

```
jdbc:mysql://dbhost:3306/dbname?user=admin&password=secret
```

Answer (score 1):

For this, you have to write the "IP address of that machine" in the connection string instead of writing localhost in it.

like : jdbc:mysql://[IP-Address]:3306/dbname

Answer (score 1):

Besides the fact that you should change the JDBC connection string from (probably)

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDB
```

or

```
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/testDB
```

To

```
jdbc:mysql://IP_OF_MACHINE:3306/testDB
```

or

```
jdbc:mysql://NAME_OF_MACHINE:3306/testDB
```

You must make sure that the machine were the mysql server is running allows TCP connections on port 3306 (default port for mysql DB). Besides this, you must make sure that the mysql engine allows connections from other machines as well.